# MySQL error 3988 "Conversion from collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci into latin1_swedish_ci impossible for parameter"

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js

I have this string `"Cavo 4x25 mmÂ² CcaFG7OR 0,6/1 kV â€“ MAE-12-02-25"` and I need to insert into a MySql table. The field has `latin1_swedish_ci` collation and I can't change it.

When I try it gives me MySQL error 3988 "Conversion from collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci into latin1_swedish_ci impossible for parameter".

I need a way to transform my string into a string valid for `latin1_swedish_ci` collation in my `nodejs` server.

The database is `MySQL version: 8.0.33 through PHP extension PDO_MySQL`.

The utf8 string arrive to the server through GraphQL.

To put the string in the database I use Sequelize upsert.

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit `COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci `?

Comment: How and where??

Comment: Show us your INSERT. Simplify if possible, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh that would lead to a collation is not valid error message as UTF8MB4 is not compatible with a latin1 collation. You need to convert the character set to latin1 first.

Comment: @Stefano where does the input string come from and what is its character set before it is passed over to mysql? What is the default character set that you specify as part of the connection?

Comment: UTF-8 is a Unicode compatible encoding, while Latin-1 is a legacy encoding that can only store a couple hundred characters from Latin script, so conversion is a potentially destructive operation (you'll have to drop characters or replace them with e.g. `?`). You can use [iconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv/) or [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) (just googled for them, I don't endorse either). But since you already have UTF-8 data, why not consider a long term table migration?

Comment: The query must work w/o problems: https://dbfiddle.uk/EAa5y4yC Reproduce your issue on the fiddle.

Comment: Those are different _character sets_ (utf8mb4 vs latin1) -- That is the real problem.  Which do you want?

Comment: @RickJames I want latin1_swedish_ci. I have to convert the string into latin1_swedish_ci before the upsert